# What is a generic implementation in the context of linking?

Tags: linker

In the "[Getting-Started](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Getting-Started)" section of `jemalloc` one possible way of linking it into an application is:

> Link jemalloc into the application at build time, but use it as a generic malloc implementation:
>
> `cc app.c -o app -L${JEMALLOC_PATH}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${JEMALLOC_PATH}/lib -ljemalloc`

As far as I understand this command it will result in both static and dynamic linking to happen. Why is this done? What is meant by "...use it as a generic malloc implementation"?

Comment: Rpath is a typical dynamic linking parameter, embedding the argument as the search path of a dynamic library inside the generated binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `jemalloc` will replace the standard `malloc` function. Contrast it with the next option:

> Compile jemalloc with an API prefix (see the --with-jemalloc-prefix configure option), link with jemalloc at build time as above, but use jemalloc distinctly from the system allocator.

In this case, you would call something like `jemalloc()` instead of `malloc()` to use it.

Comment: Okay I think I got it completely wrong in the first place. So the phrase "generic implementation" has nothing to do with linking at all. In addition I just realized there actually is no static linking happening right?